# How to pass the list of integers as json data to spring boot rest API?

Tags: java, json, spring, controller, rest

**How to pass the array of customerids and account details and receive it in the controller?**

Below is the colde of the controller.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/createaccount")
public String createAccount(@RequestBody Customerids customerids,@RequestBody Account account)
    {
        return accountservices.createAccountService(customerids, account);
    }
```

**Just wanted to know is the below given json format is right?**

**JSON passed :**

```
{
    "customerids" : {
        "customreids" : [15,16,17]
    },
    "account":{
    "type": "savings",
    "individual":"no",
    "balance": 3000.0


    }   
    
}
```

**Account :**

```
package com.tracker.pojos;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
public class Account {
    
    
    @Id
    private String account_number;
    
    @Column
    private String type;
    
    @Column
    private String individual;
    
    @Column
    private double balance;
    
    @OneToMany
    private List<Customer> customers;
    
}
```

**Customerids : **

```
package com.tracker.pojos;

import java.util.List;

import lombok.*;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customerids {
    List<Integer> customerids;
}
```

**Error thrown:**
2020-12-18 13:43:02.491  WARN 10776 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>` out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.tracker.pojos.Customerids["customerids"])]

Comment: A request has a single body. How do you expect to marshall the same into 2 classes? That obviously won't work.

Comment: How can I make it work? Is it possible to send two objects in a single request?

Comment: Create a single DTO that contains all the information, then matp that to your entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@RequestBody` annotation read the whole request body, in your code you used it twice to read tow different parts of your request body. You can not achieve it like that. It is better to define new DTO class that contains all the things that you need to receive in request body, then you can read everything you want from that DTO, it can be done like below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CreateAccountModel {

    private Integer[] customerIds;
    private Account account;
}
```

And this will be your endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/createaccount")
public String createAccount(@RequestBody CreateAccountModel createAccountModel) {
    return accountservices.createAccountService(
            createAccountModel.getCustomerIds(),
            createAccountModel.getAccount());
}
```

Then you can sen request like below:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"customerIds": [1,2,3], "account": {}}' http://localhost:8080/createaccount
```

Answer (score 1):

Your customerIds in your pojo expects an object and that object is bound to an array. Yet your Accounts class is bound to a List which is an array.

Change this:

```
"customerids" : {
    "customreids" : [15,16,17]
},
```

to just this:

```
"customerids" : [15,16,17],
```

and change this:

```
@OneToMany
private List<Customer> customers;
```

to this:

```
@OneToMany
private List<Customer> customerIds;
```